# How to check an enable link button by jquery?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

How to check a link button enable or not by using jquery.
This is link button i want to check.

```
<asp:LinkButton Enabled="true" ID="LinkButton2" runat="server">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
var a = $("#LinkButton2").attr("href");

        if (a!== undefined) {
            alert("true");
        } else {
            alert("false");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you

when using attibute id

```
var isLinkButtonEnabled = $("#LinkButton2[href]") !== undefined ? true : false;
```

when using attibute classname

```
 var isLinkButtonEnabled = $(".linkClass[href]") !== undefined ? true : false;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can check it like:

```
$("#LinkButton2").is(":disabled")
```

Here you will get Boolean value on the base of it you can find it.

Comment: This code ( $("#LinkButton2").is(":disabled") ) always return false, please check. Thanks